# CodeIgniter SQL query error handling

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, error-handling

At this moment i access my posts like this

```
http://localhost/post/174565/
```

and everything works fine, but when i am trying to access them like this

```
http://localhost/post/1745s65/
```

i am getting error

```
Error Number: 1054
Unknown column '1745s65' in 'where clause'
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id = 1745s65;
Filename: D:\Localhost\Apache\htdocs\code\system\database\DB_driver.php
Line Number: 330
```

i understand why it is there, but how to handle it? For example my users don't need to see SQL query, and i want to show them 404 page instead of this block.

Comment: post your code that queries the db based on the url.

Comment: for what you need it? post is not about debuging sql query, but handling errors :)

Comment: to see the way that you parse the query. Normally, if you used active record correctly you should not see the above error.

Comment: Ahh, ok, here it is http://pastebin.com/aPt7VYuJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
public function getPostData($iPostId) {
    $sqlQuery = $this->db->get_where('posts', array('id' => $iPostId));
    $aResult = $sqlQuery->result();

    if (empty($aResult)) {
        show_404();
    }
    else {
        return $aResult[0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Magic method! Works just perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

use execptions:

```
try{
       //here what you need to do with script
         } catch (Exception $e) {
            var_dump($e->getMessage());
            show_404();
              }
```

i think you can try also to put :

`$database['db_debug'] = FALSE;` in `config/database.php` if you want to remove  database errors from being shown

Answer (score 0):

You need to validate user input to prevent this issues.
Anyhow, Codeigniter has two preset environments: development and prodution. Check your root index.php for more information.

Comment: I thought about checking is_numeric and if SQL result !empty, thought there are some built-in functions :) Production environment changes nothing in this situation